# Problem with the minimum distribution of a set of iid random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution

Good morning, I have one small question about an exercise:

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ independent, real-valued random variables with distribution functions $F_1, . . . , F_n$
If each $X_i$ is uniform distributed on $[0, 1]$, find the density of the minimum of the set.

I first calculated $F_{X_i}(x)$

$F_{i}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& 0 & otherwise\\ 
& x &  a \leq x \leq b\\
& 1 &    x \geq b
\end{matrix}\right.$

And with the formula

$F_{minX_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& 0 & otherwise\\ 
& 1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-F_{i})=1-(1-F_{i})^n=1-(1-x)^n &  a \leq x \leq b\\
& 1 &    x \geq b
\end{matrix}\right.$

Knowing $f_{minX_i}(x)=F'_{minX_i}(x)$

$f_{minX_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& 0 & otherwise\\ 
& -n(1-x)^{n-1} &   a\leq  x \leq b
\end{matrix}\right.$

However what I can't explain is that in the solutions the right answer is:

$f_{minX_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& 0 & otherwise\\ 
& 1-nx(1-x)^{n-1} &   a\leq  x \leq b
\end{matrix}\right.$

Where does this result come from?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The tag 'distribution-theory' is for [generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) like the Dirac delta, not for probability distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $n(1-x)^{n-1}$, with no minus sign before, otherwise you would have a negative density. So up to a change of sign you are correct. I do not know what the other function refers to, it does not integrate to 1 so it is not even a density function.